# How do I write a procedure that randomly selects a pair from a list?

Tags: list, random, scheme, racket

I'm creating a checkers game and I need a procedure that randomly selects a pair from a list of pairs.

Comment: Sounds like homework... What have you tried? What doesn't work? Do you have any ideas on how you might go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(define select-random
  (lambda (ls)
    (let ((len (length ls)))         ;; find out how long the list is
      (list-ref ls (random len)))))  ;; pick one from 0 to the end
```

Answer (score 6):

I know its been a while since this question was asked
but maybe its useful for someone somewhere sometime.
You could also do:

```
     (car              ;; "car" picks the first element or the "head" of a list
       (shuffle        ;; well... shuffles
         (yourList)))
```

Comment: You should add that your solution is a highly Racket-specific one. While one may suppose that `random` is part of any Scheme implemention (although not beeing standartized) this will be not the case with `shuffle`.

Answer (score -1):

A bit more succinctly solution:

```
(define (select-random my-lst)
  (list-ref 
    my-lst 
    (random (length my-lst)))
)


> (select-random '(1 2 3 4))
3
```